# can't save file name without path , combination with grep and awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, find, filemtime

```
find /user/stc/tmp -mmin -200 -ls | grep '.txt' | awk '{print $8, $9, $10, $11}' >> tempresult.txt
```

First of all I am a newbie,
I am trying to find out ONLY .txt files modified in last week(in home/user/temp) and save the result to a file.
so some how i figured it out, but I need help with to save only file name without path.
 I can print it with

```
awk '{print \$NF}'
```

but when i try that in combination with above command It's not working as expected.

Any help/suggestion/Improvement is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /user/stc/tmp -mmin -200 -printf "%f\n" > log_file
```

or

```
  find /user/stc/tmp -mtime -7 -printf "%f\n" > log_file
```

..

`-mtime -7` # in the last 7 days

the `%f` will ignore any subdirectory the file is in.

EDIT for user request

```
 find /user/stc/tmp -mtime -7 -printf "%Td-%Tm-%TY %Tr %TY %f\n" > log_file


%Td-%Tm-%TY        #modification time: day-month-year
%Tr                #modification date time
%TY                #modification date year
```

note also linux keeps track of modification dates instead of creation dates...

Answer (score 4):

That pipeline is very over-complicated for the task.

`find` supports all the filtering and formatting support you need to do what you want without the `grep`/`awk` pipeline at all. (Not to mention that piping `grep` to `awk` is almost never necessary in the first place.)

Try:

```
find /usr/stc/tmp -mmin -200 -a -name '*.txt' -printf '%P\n'
```

- `-a` to combine `find` specifiers (though that is the default operation too)
- `-name '*.txt'` to select only files that match the desired name format
- `-printf` to select the format of the output
- `'%P\n'` to output the name of the found file with the command line argument under which it was found removed (followed by a newline).

If you actually meant just the file *name* (no path components at all) then you want the `%f` format string instead of `%P` (thanks `Xorg`).

Comment: He did say only the filename, not the path - that would be "%p" rather than "%P".  Also, it would help to have a "-type f" (just in case).

Comment: "-mmin 200" is a lot shorter than a week (I would just use "-mtime -7").

Comment: using the "%p" will not ignore any leading subdirectory the file is in..."%f" will do..refer to find manpages

Comment: @Xrog Thanks guys for the help..But I need to take only few fields, **File name without path, Date time and year**. This will out put all the details. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want the `%t` or `%T<k>` format strings for that. Look at the find manual for more details about the `%T<k>` specifies to see what you can get from it.

Comment: @Reyaz eon...I was at work...however i edited my answer for your request